# How to update column based on data from another table (Mapinfo Pro)?

Tags: mapinfo, intersection, table, update

What I want to do is update column (Table A) by values from another table (Table B) using condition intersects. There are few objects in table B which intersects one object from table A. When I try to do this I get only one value to column (Table A), but these are not all. How to update column by all values from Table B?

[image: example]

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "by all"? Show an example.

Comment: Something like that
https://i.imgur.com/gwHWs2c.jpg

Comment: The MapBasic SQL dialect does not have a function like `group_concat()` or `string_agg()`. Would it be possible to upload the data into a real database?